# Remove the contextual menu when the routes getting change

Tags: angularjs

I stored contextual menus in the array, and i doing the action using callback function. Need to clear the array when routes getting changed.

Answer (score 1):

So it depends if you are using ui-router or ng-router.

In essence you want to bind to the route change event, and these events named differently depending on the router you are using.

For ui-router you could do something like this:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function() {

    $scope.contextMenu.splice(0, $scope.contextMenu.length);  

});
```